# Import brand products with csv

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, php, import

I am using venus theme brands extension for brands management. Now I want to import the products using brands. There is an option for importing brands using the CSV but I am not able to find any demo CSV. So, is there any dummy CSV we can have for venus theme brands import?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample sheet

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-jOLMcyl2XSVz92GOvCYCRC6kA_8omWz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What about other product attributes? It contains only 2 columns

Comment: Also getting this error "Can not found product or brand item to imported.
"

Comment: 1. in this section you can import other attributes. it's brand modules import functionality.

Comment: 2. is SKU exist in your magento? I mean you changes test product SKU to your sku?

Comment: By other attributes I mean price, qty etc. And Yes SKU does exists and I have changed that too.

Comment: update attribute is different thing in your case. becuase if you wanna update price,name or any attribute. you can update in default magento import section.

here we are talking about brand only. your brand module has seprate table.

Comment: So, you are saying that I can not import products from here ?

Comment: exactly !! for product import go to ``System -> Data Transfer -> Import ->Entity Type -> Products``

Comment: Ok thanks. So, what if I want to import the products on the basis of brands ? There is no option for brands in the demo csv provided by Magento

Comment: go to ``System -> Data Transfer -> Import ->Entity Type -> Products`` here you will get sample sheet once select ``products``

Comment: Yes, but there is no "brands" column in there

Comment: please export products once instead of import. you will get brand column and brand is not magento default attribute so you can not able to find in sample csv but you can add in your csv.

Comment: Note: still you need to import also in brand module(window in your question). because brand module has also custom table too and also that relation required too..I hope now it's clear

Comment: Yes, thank you @Gohil Rajesh